# Using Salesforce API Explorer for documenting Apex REST services

Tags: rest-api, documentation

Is there a way to use the [Salesforce REST API Explorer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Account) with an org to have documentation on custom Apex REST classes show up?

[image: Force.com REST API Explorer screenshot]

Perhaps there is something similar to Lightning Components that have the "Link to your org" feature? [image: Lightning Components documentation, showing "link to your org"]

Comment: Nope but it's a Good Idea that belongs on IdeaExchange. Not quite what you're asking for but along these lines: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cQsxQAE .